# Get origin domain in NodeJS - Express

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get the domain from the request in nodejs, the request originates from PHP and when I get origin in Nodejs I get undefined.

This is my code in PHP: (domain1.com)

```
    $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://myNodedomain.com/sendAlert',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('token' => '3242342332'),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

This is my code in NodeJs: (mynodedomain.com)

```
app.post('/sendAlert', async (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.get('host'));
   console.log(req.get('origin'));
});
```

The desired result is:
https://domain1.com/

Any solution?

Comment: If the request is coming from a PHP script, there is no way to reliably associate a domain with that.  That's just some random client somewhere at some IP address.  That client could tell you what domain it was at by setting a referrer header on the request or you could try to do a reverse DNS lookup on its IP address and see if that IP address is associated with a particular domain, but neither of those is guaranteed to work and cannot be relied upon unless the requesting host is cooperating with you and can be trusted.

Comment: Your PHP code is not sending the origin header. Therefore it is not possible to get the origin domain due to how TCP/IP and HTTP works

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll implement it in another way instead of origin.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super familiar with PHP, but adding something like this might work:

```php
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Origin: domain1.com']);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).